# Vaadin charts and table sync

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-charts

Is it possible to get the distance between bars in a vaadin bar chart and in a parallel table, sync the table or treetable row heights to match?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot to illustrate?

Comment: thanks @tk12 ....Don't have one, but think of a gantt chart, where the left part is a table and the right part is a chart

Comment: If you're thinking to make something similar to a Gantt chart, there is this [great add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/gantt) that can help you achieve that with ease.

Comment: Going to put it up as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/gantt) Gantt chart add-on for Vaadin.

Here's a [demo](http://tomivirtanen.app.fi/gantt-demo/) that you can check its core capabilities.

And [here](https://github.com/tltv/gantt) is its source code.